# Argument type 'object' is not assignable to parameter type 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following tag in my aspx page

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkFlags" name="chkFlags" value="<%#DataBinder.Eval(DataItemContainer, "DataItem.Tag_ID") %>" <%#SelectTags(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Tag_ID")) %>/>
```

I am getting the following error:

> Argument type 'object' is not assignable to parameter type 'string'

The section of the line that is highlighted is:

```
<%#SelectTags(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Tag_ID"))
```

My routine for SelectTags is as follows:

```
        public string SelectTags(string Tag_ID)
    {

        string[] aTags = mobjFormat.StripObjectToString(Request.Form["chkFlags"]).Split(Convert.ToChar(","));  //added square brackets to Request.Form and syntax to convert from string to char 10/21/15 Max //
        string sItem = "";
        string sReturn = "";

        mobjSecurity.MessageStack_Insert("Procedure", "SelectTags", "");

        foreach (string sItem_loopVariable in aTags)
        {
            sItem = sItem_loopVariable;
            if (sItem.Trim() == Tag_ID.ToString().Trim())  //added parenthesis to Trim and ToString 10/21/15 Max //
            {
                sReturn = " checked='checked' ";
            }
        }

        mobjSecurity.MessageStack_Insert("sReturn", sReturn, "SelectTags");
        return sReturn;

    }
```

I am not sure what needs to be accomplished to fix this error, perhaps I am just missing something (I have spent many hours looking over this code)

Can someone point me in the direction to take to fix this TIA

Comment: `DataBinder.Eval` returns an `object` and your `SelectTags` wants a `string`.  It looks like you need a cast or a conversion maybe with `ToString()`?

Comment: Thank you Juharr!  I cannot believe that was it.  Maybe time to go home to bed :-)

Comment: Was about to answer this, then realised the answer is in a comment! You should add the answer as an answer so it can be accepted! :)

Comment: @SpaceBison  -- Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Juharr points out I was just missing the ToString conversion on the line.  So I fixed it as follows:

```
<%#SelectTags(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Tag_ID").ToString())
```